# How can I count the number of digits in a number up to 1000 digits in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, count, digits

**How can I count the number of digits in a number up to 1000 digits in C or C++**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num,counter=0;

    scanf("%d",&num);

    while(num!=0){
        num/=10;
        counter++;
    }

    printf("%d\n",counter);
}
```

This code works just for numbers up to 10 digits — I don't know why.

Comment: Because an `int` type on modern CPU's cannot hold a number that large.

Comment: read it in as a string

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, I don't know if we'll ever see an `int` hold 1000 digits.

Comment: Thx. But, How can i count the digits of a string ?

Comment: @user3803192, If all characters are known to be digits, `s.size()`.

Comment: @TemplateRex 512bits only store approximately 150 digits (base 10)

Comment: @TemplateRex, Still only like 150 digits, but alright, fine. I don't know we'll ever see a *common* `int` hold 1000 digits.

Comment: @chris sorry, I misread indeed, 1,000 digits is insane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since most computers can't hold an integer that is 1000 digits, you will either have to operate on the input as a string or use a *Big Number* library.  Let's try the former.

When treating the input as a string, each digit is a character in the range of `'0'` to `'9'`, inclusive.

So, this boils down to counting characters:

```
std::string text;
cin >> text;
const unsigned int length = text.size();
unsigned int digit_count = 0;
for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
  if (!std::isdigit(text[i]))
  {
    break;
  }
  ++digit_count;
}
cout << "text has " << digit_count << "digits\n";
```

Comment: Instead of the loop, you could use `std::find_if_not` and `std::distance` to get the count.

Comment: @MohamedAlNajjar, That error can be solved by learning from a hello world program.