# How to find the number of digits int digits in c upto 100 or 1000 digits?

Tags: c, loops, count, logic

This is my code:`

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
void main() {
    int n;
    int count = 0;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
 
    // iterate until n becomes 0
    // remove last digit from n in each iteration
    // increase count by 1 in each iteration
        
    while (n != 0) {
        n /= 10;     // n = n/10
        ++count;
    }
 
    printf("Number of digits: %lld", count);  
}
```

I am able to run the code finely but when I enter ***15 or 16 digits*** of number as input then it always shows me that the number of digits is `10`. And another problem with this code is that suppose if I input `000` then I want the output to be `3 digits` but this code is not able to do that as the condition in the `while` loop becomes instantly false. So how write a code that enables me to take ***upto 100 or 1000 digits as input*** and also enables me to input ***0s*** as well.

> Note: This program should be solved using a loop and in C language
> I found a answer to the question here in stackoverflow written in c++ that I couldn't even understand as I am a beginner and I am learning C.
> Link  to the answer:
> [How can I count the number of digits in a number up to 1000 digits in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562607/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-digits-in-a-number-up-to-1000-digits-in-c-c)

Comment: Work with strings, not integers, and count the length of the string.

Comment: An int only holds 32 or 64 bits, so can't hold a 100-digit number, which requires 100's of bits.

Comment: Plain `int` normally runs up to two billion, so 9 or 10 digits.  Anything more and you need a bigger data type such as `long long`. That'll get you to 16 digits.

Comment: @stark ceil(log(1e100)/log(2)) = 333 bits to be specific.

Comment: Given the requirement to count strings of zero digits this is clearly a string handling question, and an arithmetic solution is not required and won't work even for input of less than 10 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reading a number, read a string and count the digits:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char buffer[10000];
    int n;

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    if (scanf("%9999s", buffer) == 1) {
        for (n = 0; buffer[n] >= '0' && buffer[n] <= '9'; n++)
            continue;
        printf("Number of digits: %d\n", n);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

You can also use the `scanf()` scanset feature to perform the test in one step:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char buffer[10000];
    int n;

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    if (scanf("%9999[0-9]%n", buffer, &n) == 1) {
        printf("Number of digits: %d\n", n);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you but what is the value of n?

Comment: @ShubhamBhandari:  `n` is not the number, it is the number of digits. It is computed in the `for` loop in the first version, and stored by `scanf()` via the `%n` conversion in the second version. The number is not converted, it remains in text form in the `buffer` array.

Comment: @ chqrile What if I want the user to input numbers (integer) only but not any other characters  or alphabet?

Comment: @ShubhamBhandari: you cannot prevent the user from entering what they want. You can only detect offending characters. `scanf("%d", &n)` will be successful if the user types optional spaces followed by an optional sign followed by at least 1 digit. `scanf("%9999s", buffer)` will accept optional spaces and any string and the loop will only count initial digits and `scanf("%9999[0-9]%n", buffer, &n)` will only read digits, but in all cases, the user can type other characters after the digits and then hit enter. Further tests are required to detect invalid input.

Comment: what does the if condition mean int the 2nd program? this one: `if (scanf("%9999[0-9]%n", buffer, &n) == 1)`

Comment: @ chqrlie And another thing is that how can I know if the user inputs string value or an integer value?

Comment: @ShubhamBhandari: `scanf()` returns the number of successful conversions: there is only 1 conversion specification `%[0-9]` (`%n` does not count) so the return value should be `1` if the user typed at least one digit. It will be `0` if the user typed something else and `EOF` if the input stream has been closed (by typing Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z).

Comment: @ShubhamBhandari: the user types characters, `scanf()` can convert these characters as a number if the number is small enough. You seem to want to handle large numbers and to handle leading `0` specifically, so you cannot let `scanf()` convert the input as a number, you must get the input as a string.

Comment: sorry if I am bothering you but what is the %9999s and continue in the 1st program? is it a %9999s some kind of format specifier? I didn't actually understood the program. Pardon me.

Comment: @ShubhamBhandari: the number between the `%` and the format specifer (`s`, `[`, `d`, ...) is the maximum number of characters to consume from the input for the conversion. giving `scanf()` this information is important to prevent it from writing beyond the end of the destination array for `s` and `[` conversions. `continue;` is a statement you can use in a loop to branch to the next iteration directly (in case of a `for` loop, the increment clause is evaluated, hence `n` is incremented. I write this statement to underscore the fact that the loop is empty, in this case it could be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking int variable and you are trying to count a number like whose digit is 100 or 1000. it will not fit with int. so take input as a string and count the length of string.

Answer (score 0):

32 bits signed integer has the max value equals 2,147,483,647 so, if you input a bigger one, it will not be stored. I'd make it receiving a string and get its length, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int len = strlen("123123123123132");
```